# How to keep textbox value and gridview value after Edit gridview record page navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form which is basically a search form where user should be able to search records based on ID, Date and some other criteria. The search result will be then display on gridview. I have Edit functionality for each records on the gridview.
When user click on Edit of any record it will navigate to the edit page where user should be able to edit and update.
Everything works fine upto here.
But i have a back button on the Edit page once i click on the back page it will come back to the search page.

I want to keep the previously searched value on the textbox and the search result on the gridview too but i am not able to.

I tried both session variable and cookies but it is not working.

So please help me how can i do this??

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: try queryString like: `yourpage.aspx?search_text=your_val` and pass it on the button click

Comment: I am using querystring to pass record ID while navigating from search page to edit page to update that record . But the search form have multiple textbox and dropdown so how can i use querystring and also how to keep the gridview value as it is?